# I don't understand about higher-order function parameter passed in example

Tags: javascript, function, higher-order-functions

I was reading article about higher-order functions. And they give code example like this:

```js
var humans = function(data) {
  return data.filter(function(character) {
    return character.species === 'human';
  })
}

var images = function(data) {
  return data.map(function(character) {
    return character.img;
  })
}

function compose(func1, func2) {
  return function(data) {
    return func2(func1(data));
  };
}

var displayCharacterImages = compose(humans, images);
```

The one thing that's I don't understand is where is the data are gonna passed in `compose` function? I mean we only pass func1, func2 as params. So where can the data go in `compose` function?
I am still a newbie so please help me understand this

Comment: `displayCharacterImages` is still a function, in your example no data is passed to it yet. You can later do `displayCharacterImages(someData)`, and it will be equivalent to `images(humans(someData))`.

Comment: So Javascript just knows that the missing `data` part automatically match `someData` when we do `displayCharacterImages(someData)` right? But like how's that possible, I think the `data` must be define as some params passed in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Compose` function returns a *function* not a value.
So when you call `compose` you get a *function*.
`displayCharacterImages` is a *function* not a value.

The `data` variable is the **returned functions** argument.

Basically, you will be doing this :
`displayCharacterImages(foo)`
So `data` will get the value you passed in `foo`.

Comment: but why does `data` know to get the value passed in `displayCharacterImages`, we don't define it as a param, so is that something automatically?

Comment: @callmeGi a function can return a function, basically `displayCharacterImages` is a function now, with `data` as an argument.

Comment: so `displayCharacterImages(value)` and `data` will get the `value` automatically, right? So magical, thank you!

Comment: @callmeGi :), try reading about function returning a function on internet